# sed - replace multiline string between patterns in different lines

Tags: sql, shell, sed

I have few .sql files that contain comments marked as '/* */'
Comment can start and end at the same line, but mostly there is a multiline comment.

[UPDATED] Example:

```
    /*=======WHATEVER=======*/
    SELECT * FROM TABLE 
    WHERE
        /* PERIOD_DTE IN
                (SELECT MAX(PERIOD_DTE) 
                 FROM TABLE WHERE PERIOD_DTE < '1900-01-01')
                 AND FIELD1 = 100
                 AND FIELD2 IS NULL
        */
    FIELD3 IS NULL
```

Is it possible to use sed function for replace that kind of comment as an empty string?

Comment: I don't know SQL, so could you update the example in the question to show how any single line comments look in you use case please? Thanks

Comment: Of course :) Example updated.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it for your example (with GNU sed):

```
sed 's_\*/_\n*/_' your_file | sed '/\/\*/,/\*\//d'
```

The ways it's working is as follows:

- In the first command I'm using `_` as a pattern delimiter to avoid needing
  to escape the `\` characters.
- The first command breaks any single line comment into a multiple line
  comment so that we can deal with one situation in the second command.
- The second command deletes everything including and between lines matching
  the patterns `/*` and `*/`

So with the example input:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE
    /* PERIOD_DTE IN
            (SELECT MAX(PERIOD_DTE) 
             FROM TABLE WHERE PERIOD_DTE < '1900-01-01')
             AND FIELD1 = 100
             AND FIELD2 IS NULL
    */
    /* SINGLE LINE COMMENT */
FIELD3 IS NULL
```

So the two steps are:

```
sed 's_\*/_\n*/_' your_file
```

outputs:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE
    /* PERIOD_DTE IN
            (SELECT MAX(PERIOD_DTE)
             FROM TABLE WHERE PERIOD_DTE < '1900-01-01')
             AND FIELD1 = 100
             AND FIELD2 IS NULL

*/
    /* SINGLE LINE COMMENT
*/
FIELD3 IS NULL
```

and

```
sed '/\/\*/,/\*\//d'
```

outputs:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE
FIELD3 IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly when ,sql file looks like the one in example. Of course our business users put an one line comment ... at the beggining of the file :) - so I have a one line comment at the beginning of the file and a multi line comment somwhere in file. In that situation your solution removes all the code between two comments - If I understand this correctly we need to remove a one line comment first, then remove a multi line one?

Comment: @Darkeue I tried my command on the updated example and it seems to work? I also added a second multi-line comment after the line `FIELD3 IS NULL` and it also worked? So I don't understand what you mean when you so my solution removes all the code between two comments?

Comment: I use m_cat at first to read the file and then I use your solution and the result is only "FIELD3 IS NULL" - only last line of code. Is m_cat a problem?

Comment: @Darkeue I'm not familiar with m_cat so I can't answer this, sorry